# Не могу найти ошибку в коде класса Array. В каком то месте память очищается более одного раза

Tags: c++, массивы, классы

Написал класс Array в образовательных целях. Предполагается, что тип "T" не имеет оператор присваивания. Где-то в коде происходит переочистка выделенной памяти. Не могу найти.

```
template <typename T>
class Array {
private:
size_t size_;
T * data_;
public:
Array(size_t size, const T& value = T()) //КОНСТРУКТОР ПО УМОЛЧАНИЮ
{
    size_ = size;
    data_ = static_cast<T*>(operator new (size_ * sizeof(T)));
    for (int i = 0;i<size_;++i){
        new (&data_[i]) T(value);
    }
}

Array():data_(NULL), size_(0){} //ПУСТОЙ КОНТРУКТОР

Array(const Array & a) { //КОНСТРУКТОР КОПИРОВАНИЯ
    size_ = a.size_;
    data_ = static_cast<T*>(operator new (size_ * sizeof(T)));
    for (int i = 0;i<size_;++i){
        new (&data_[i]) T(a.data_[i]);
    }
}

~Array() { //ДЕСТРУКТОР
    for (int i=0;i<size_;++i){
        data_[i].~T();
    }
    operator delete (data_);
}

Array& operator=(const T & a) { //ОПЕРАТОР ПРИСВОЕНИЯ
    if (data_!=a.data_) {
        for (int i=0;i<size_;++i){
            data_[i].~T();
        }
        operator delete (data_);

        size_ = a.size_;
        data_ = static_cast<T*>(operator new (size_ * sizeof(T)));
        for (int i = 0;i<size_;++i){
            new (&data_[i]) T(a.data_[i]);
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

size_t size() const {return size_;}

T& operator[](size_t i){return data_[i];}
const T& operator[](size_t i) const{return * (data_ + i);}
};
```

Comment: Ну, и как по-вашему мы должны определить, что объекты этого класса удаляются два раза?!

Comment: Представьте минимальную компилируемую программу, которая демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Что это `static_cast<T*>(operator new (size_ * sizeof(T))) ... new (&data_[i]) T(a.data_[i]);`?? Почему не  `new T[size_]`]

Comment: @Санат Б У вас уже в операторе присваивания имеется проблема в данном цикле, так как data_ может быть равной NULL.  for (int i=0;i<size_;++i){
            data_[i].~T();
        }

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, тогда и `size==0`

Comment: @Санат Б Та же самая проблема имеется в деструкторе.

Comment: @Lol4t0  Ах, да, спасибо.:)

Comment: Вообще вы бы пример привели, при котором "происходит переочистка выделенной памяти", и уже было лучше

Comment: Гм, это задание из курса по C++ не степике: https://stepic.org/course/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5-C++-7/syllabus?module=6

Comment: Это вопрос-задание в учебном курсе на степике, раздел 6.1 Шаблоны классов: https://stepic.org/course/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5-C++-7/syllabus?module=6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, что проблема связана с тем, что вы не определили копирующий оператор присваивания.

В этом случае используется определенный по умолчанию компилятором оператор присваивания, которые просто копирует данные. Поэтому после использования такого оператора будет утечка памяти, и два указателя будут указывать один и тот же адрес.

А это

```
Array& operator=(const T & a) { //ОПЕРАТОР ПРИСВОЕНИЯ
    if (data_!=a.data_) {
        for (int i=0;i<size_;++i){
            data_[i].~T();
        }
        operator delete (data_);

        size_ = a.size_;
        data_ = static_cast<T*>(operator new (size_ * sizeof(T)));
        for (int i = 0;i<size_;++i){
            new (&data_[i]) T(a.data_[i]);
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

вообще неверный код и не является копирующим оператором присваивания. Я думаю, что вы имели в виду в качестве параметра объект класса `Array`, а не объект типа `T`.

То есть этот оператор должен быть объявлен как

```
Array& operator=(const Array<T> & a) { //ОПЕРАТОР ПРИСВОЕНИЯ
```

И это

```
Array(size_t size, const T& value = T()) //КОНСТРУКТОР ПО УМОЛЧАНИЮ
```

не конструктор по умолчанию, а конструктор с параметрами. Конструктор по умолчанию у вас тот конструктор, который вы называете пустым.

Кроме того данный конструктор с параметрами у вас является преобразующим  конструктором, так как он может преобразовать любой целочисленный тип в объект класса Array.  Поэтому лучше его объявить со спецификатором функции `explicit`

```
explicit Array(size_t size, const T& value = T())
```